# Undefined reference to in C++

Tags: c++, oop

**Please, can someone help me to solve this error.**

the error I get is *"undefined reference to"* all functions, constructors and destructor that I implemented.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vecteur.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Vecteur vect1(2,1,3),vect2(3,6,4);
    vect1.affiche();
}
```

vecteur.hpp

```
class Vecteur{
    public:
    Vecteur();
    Vecteur(float abscisse, float ordonnee, float hauteur);
    ~Vecteur();
    void affiche();

    private:
    float m_abscisse;
    float m_ordonnee;
    float m_hauteur;
};
```

vecteur.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vecteur.hpp"
using namespace std;


Vecteur::Vecteur():m_abscisse(0),m_ordonnee(0),m_hauteur(0)
{

}
Vecteur::Vecteur(float abscisse, float ordonnee, float hauteur):m_abscisse(abscisse),m_ordonnee(ordonnee),m_hauteur(0)
{

}
Vecteur::~Vecteur(){
    cout<<"L'adresse du vecteur détruit est : "<<this;
}
void Vecteur::affiche()
{
    cout <<"("<<m_abscisse<<","<<m_ordonnee<<","<<m_hauteur<<")";
}
```

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9WNr.png)

Comment: You should add `vecteur.cpp` to the arguments of the compiler. Something like `g++ main.cpp vecteur.cpp`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

your IDE miss vecteur.cpp durring compiling, I think you need to write a CmakeLists.txt or Makefile to specify how your program will be compiled ( flags, libraries,..).

to test quickly your program use this command

```
g++ main.cpp vecteur.cpp -o output && ./output
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution:
The mistake I did is **I didn't create a C++ project** in visual studio code.